# How do i extract only abbreviation following acronyms inside the brackets by mapping each Capital letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, artificial-intelligence

```
 a = "The process maps are similar to Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)"
```

input = "The process maps are similar to Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)"

output = Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)

I want to write a python scripts where I have that piece of text, from that I want to extract full for of given acronyms inside the brackets `(MEPF)` and full form is `Manual Excellence Process Framework` I want to append only full from by match each uppercase letter from inside the brackets.

my idea was when ever acronyms appears inside the bracket that will map each capital letter for example (MEPF) starting from last Letter F that will match last word befoure the bracket here it is Framwork, then P (Pocess) then E(Excellence ) finaly M (manual) so final output will be full form(Manual Excellence Process Framework) can you try once this way that will be realy helpfull for me

Comment: What is the exact output you expect here?

Comment: input = "The process maps are similar to Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)"

output = Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)

Comment: Input will be any sentence or paragraph, output will be abbreviation by following capital letter acronyms inside the brackets  input = "The process maps are similar to Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)"  output = Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple regex and a bit of post-processing:

```
a = "I like International Business Machines (IBM). The Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)"

import re
m = re.findall(r'([^)]+) \(([A-Z]+)\)', a)
out = {b: ' '.join(a.split()[-len(b):]) for a,b in m}

out
```

output:

```
{'IBM': 'International Business Machines',
 'MEPF': 'Manual Excellence Process Framework'}
```

If you want to check the the acronym actually matches the words:

```
out = {b: ' '.join(a.split()[-len(b):]) for a,b in m
       if all(x[0]==y for x,y in zip(a.split()[-len(b):], b))
       }
```

example

```
a = "No match (ABC). I like International Business Machines (IBM). The Manual Excellence Process Framework (MEPF)."

m = re.findall(r'([^)]+) \(([A-Z]+)\)', a)
{b: ' '.join(a.split()[-len(b):]) for a,b in m
 if all(x[0]==y for x,y in zip(a.split()[-len(b):], b))
}

# {'IBM': 'International Business Machines',
#  'MEPF': 'Manual Excellence Process Framework'}
```

Answer (score 0):

i make your question as a challenge i am a beginner so i hope to be this answer useful  for you and thank you for you question :

```
a = "process maps are similar to Manual Excellence Process 
Framework (MEPF)"

full = ''
ind = a.index('(')
ind2 = a.index(')')
acr = a[ind+1:ind2]
for i in a.split():
    for j in range (len(acr)):
        if acr[j] == i[0] and len(i) > 1:
            word = i
            full = full  + word + ' '
print(full)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, my idea was when ever acronyms appears inside the bracket that will map each capital letter for example (MEPF)  starting from last Letter F that will match last word befoure the bracket here it is Framwork, then P (Pocess) then E(Excellence ) finaly M (manual)  so final output will be full form(Manual Excellence Process Framework) can you try once  this way that will be realy helpfull for me

Comment: I tried with example text a = "The CCI had passed the final order against United Breweries Ltd (UBL), SABMiller India Ltd, now renamed as Anheuser Busch InBev India Ltd (AB InBev), and Carlsberg India Private Ltd (CIPL), among other entities."  i got different output. kind of not expect.